# Received activation link by email but when clicked, it displays an error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Registration sends an activation mail. However, when I click on it, it displays an error as shown below:

[image: when I am clicking on activation link]

Comment: Your view page to be displayed on activation link click is not found so check `emailconfirm.blade.php` exists or not .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 check in your view page (emailconfirm.blade.php) available or not. 
 if available then check the path is correctly given or not.
```